# Wicked_pdf multiple pdf's one same page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, wicked-pdf

Is it possible to have multiple pdf links on one page using wicked_pdf? I can't seem to find any information on this.

For example I have a daily sales report and a weekly sales report that I want to be accessible as a pdf download on the show page.

Controller

```
format.pdf do
 render pdf: "#{@sales.name}", 
 template: 'trials/sales_day_report',
 disposition: 'attachment'
end
format.pdf do
 render pdf: "#{@sales.name}", 
 template: 'trials/sales_weekly_report',
 disposition: 'attachment'
end
```

Show

```
<%= link_to 'Download Daily Report', sale_path(format: 'pdf') %>
<%= link_to 'Download Weekly Report', sale_path(format: 'pdf') %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need yo pass an extra parameter whitin your links like this:

```
<%= link_to 'Download Daily Report', sale_path(format: 'pdf', sale_type: 'daily') %>
<%= link_to 'Download Weekly Report', sale_path(format: 'pdf', sale_type: 'weekly') %>
```

Then, interpolate that paramater in your pdf template route:

```
format.pdf do
  render pdf: "#{@sales.name}",
  template: "trials/sales_#{params[:sale_type]}_report",
  disposition: 'attachment'
end
```